# Fetch Data_type from mysql Table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I use this code:

```
select data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = '$tableName' and column_name = '$column_name'
```

But after `echo`, it's returning `1`. But when I run it in phpmyadmin sql it's returning `data_type` of column.

I want `data_type` of Mysql Table column (I'm using Wordpress).

Comment: show your `echo` related code snippet

Comment: I tryed all of this >  $vv = mysql_query($query);

     $x = mysql_field_type ( $vv , 0);

     echo $x;
     var_dump($x);

Comment: $query = "select data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = '$tableName' and column_name = '$column_name' ";

     $vv = $wpdb->query($query);
     $x = mysql_fetch_field ( $query );

     echo $x;
     var_dump($x);

Comment: @MamunurRashid please see my answer, I've solved your problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right one, I also used it.
$sql="SELECT data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '$tableName' AND column_name = '$column_name' ";

Answer (score 5):

> you can simply get the datatype as below. where ever you like . you can change different data_type by changing the value of "$tableName" and "$column_name" below

```
<?php
global $wpdb;$prefix=$wpdb->prefix;
$tableName=$prefix.'posts';
$column_name='post_title';
echo $sql="SELECT data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '$tableName' AND column_name = '$column_name' ";
  $dataType = $wpdb->get_var($sql);        
echo $dataType;?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this in wordpress. You should use `get_var()` or `get_row()` method.

> $wpdb->query() returns only (int|false) Number of rows
>   affected/selected or false on error

```
$dataType = $wpdb->get_var("select data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = '$tableName' and column_name = '$column_name' ");        
echo $dataType;exit;
```

**Edited :**

I have tried in my local like. you should try by setting these two varibale `$tableName='wp_posts'; $column_name='post_title';` like below :

```
$tableName='wp_posts';
$column_name='post_title';
$data = $wpdb->get_var("select data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = '$tableName' and column_name = '$column_name'"); 
echo $data;
```

Output

```
mediumtext
```

Comment: Where is your comment related to get_var() ?

Comment: Sorry for late. It can be some late for check I'm working on Clint project.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently too many tools (PHP / PhpAdmin) are getting in the way of going straight to the answer.  If you are just looking for the answer, use the mysql commandline tool:

```
mysql> SELECT data_type FROM information_schema.columns
    ->     WHERE column_name = 'id'
    ->       AND table_schema = 'try'
    ->       AND table_name = 'a';
+-----------+
| data_type |
+-----------+
| int       |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you do need to use the result in PHP, the treat it like any other `SELECT` -- use the appropriate API calls in `mysqli_*` or `PDO` to run the `SELECT`, then fetch the rows (one row in this case) and look at the columns (one column in this case).

Note that you should include the `table_schema = ...` in case there is another database with the same `table_name` and `column_name`.

Answer (score 2):

The values of `$tableName` and `$column_name` in your Wordpress are not what you are expecting them to be.

> I use this code:
>
> ```
> select data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = '$tableName' and column_name = '$column_name'
> ```
>
> But after echo, it's returning 1. But when I run it in phpmyadmin sql it's returning data_type of column.

Because when you are running it in phpmyadmin you are substituting the values for `$tableName` and `$column_name` explicitly. Whatever values you are substituting explicitly are what you expect `$tableName` and `$column_name` to be inside your Wordpress. But they're not what you are expecting them to be. You'll discover this by explicitly setting the values inside your Wordpress.

```
select data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'x' and column_name = 'y'
```

There isn't enough information in your question to figure out exactly what is wrong. All you've shown is a partial of what the code looks like. Nonetheless, the next step in the debugging process will be to explicitly set the variables, and then work backwards from the point of error.

```
$tableName = 'x';
$column_name = 'y';
// ...
select data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = '$tableName' and column_name = '$column_name'
```

Debugging backwards you'll find the bug.

Answer (score 1):

It's printing one because that's the return value -- it means there is an error. You're trying to fetch a result set from a string (your query) rather than from the actual result object.

This is what will make it work:

```
$tableName = mysqli_real_escape_string($tableName);
$columnName = mysqli_real_escape_string($tableName);
$query = "select data_type ";
$query .= "from information_schema.columns ";
$query .= "where table_name = '$tableName' ";
$query .= "and column_name = '$column_name' ";
$vv = $wpdb->query($query); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($vv);
```

In your comment, you said this was your code statement:

```
$query = "select data_type ";
$query .= "from information_schema.columns ";
$query .= "where table_name = '$tableName' ";
$query .= "and column_name = '$column_name' ";
$vv = $wpdb->query($query); 
$x = mysql_fetch_field ( $query ); 
echo $x; 
var_dump($x);
```

Answer (score 1):

$sql="SELECT data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '$tableName' AND column_name = '$column_name' ";